# React JS buttons with css align on top of each other instead of horizontal align

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working on React JS application. I have two buttons which I wanted to be equal width. Initially they are aligned next to each other. When I increased the button size with col-sm-8, the button were rendered on top of each other. When I hit F12, I checked that there was no margin or padding next to the button and confused why the buttons are forced to aligned on top of each other when the width is increased. There is enough room.

I tried a few styling changes like justify-items: center, aligned-items: center but so far nothing is working.

Here is my code

```
<div className={'my-toolbar'}>
 <div className={''my-btn-group}
   <button className={'col-sm-8'}>{'AAAAAAAA'}</button>
   <button className={'col-sm-8'}>{'BBBBBBBB'}</button>
 </div>
</div>

css

.my-toolbar {
 display: flex;
 aligned-items: center;
 font-size; 16px
}

.my-btn-group {
 display: inline-block
 white-space: nowrap
}
```

Comment: There is no property called `aligned-items` it is `align-items: center;` btw I am not saying this is a resolution, just pointed the right property.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two type of display in CSS `display: inline-block` and `display: flex`
concentrate only on `flex` try this

```
.my-toolbar {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 font-size; 16px
 }

 .my-btn-group {
 flex: 1
 }
```

Comment: when I changed display:flex, the first button with only 4 characters, the width shrunk to the size of the content. I prefer both buttons to be equal width and the size of the largest content which is why I set it to col-sm-8. Can that be done? Thanks

Comment: then you need to put each button inside a div

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
.my-btn-group{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
```

and remove display:inline-block and white-space...

Comment: when I changed display:flex, the first button with only 4 characters, the width shrunk to the size of the content. I prefer both buttons to be equal width and the size of the largest content which is why I set it to col-sm-8. Can that be done? Thanks

Comment: not really, it force the first button width to shrink to the size of the content. I am have to find something else beside col-sm-8

Comment: Put each button inside a div or give your (.my-btn-group) flex-shrink:#pix. Like:
.my-btn-group{flex-shrink:3rem;}